# Passing bins cut with pandas into a function

Tags: pandas, function, binning

I have a dataframe that I've cut as follows:

```
def binning(col, cut_points, labels = None):
    '''
    From https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/01/12-pandas-techniques-python-data-manipulation/
    '''
    #   Define min and max values:
    minval = col.min()
    maxval = col.max()
    #   Create list by adding min and max to cut_points
    break_points = [minval] + cut_points + [maxval]

    #   If no labels provided, use default labels 0 ... (n-1)
    if not labels:
        labels = range(len(cut_points)+1)

    #   Binning using cut function of pandas
    colBin = pd.cut(col,bins=break_points,labels=labels,include_lowest=True, duplicates = 'drop')
    return colBin

cut_points = [0.5,3.5,4.5]
labels = ["z<0.5","0.5<=z<3.5","3.5<z<=4.5","z>4.5"]
sources["z_bin"] = binning(sources["z"], cut_points, labels)
print(pd.value_counts(sources["z_bin"], sort=False))
```

and I'd like to pass each bin to a function that I've written, to plot a scatter graph. I know that `pandas` has plotting functions, and wrappers for `matplotlib`, but I'd like to use my custom function if possible, to keep the format consistent with the rest of my graphs. My custom function is called as follows:

```
plotSelected(x, y, name_for_y_series, ...a couple of other arguments)
```

so is there any way that I can plot the y series against the binned x values? Something like

```
plotSelected(x_binned, y, name_for_y_series, ...a couple of other arguments)
```

I don't know how `pandas` organises its bins. Are they lists, or tuples, or something else?

Comment: What is `qf.binning` here? Seems you are not using `pd.cut`?

Comment: Sorry...another custom function. I've added it to my snippet.